# iOS : Cannot generate .ipa for .xodeproj which has zxing api

Tags: ios, zxing, ipa

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/iphone) and built it successfully. Now I want to distribute to check in various devices. When I click distribute, get these options as shown in the image.

I have two .xcodeprojs in my project. One is mine and other is ZXingWidget.xcodeproj. I added ad hoc distribution certificate (in build settings) for both .xcodeproj i.e. mine and ZXingWidget. Still get these options.

How do I get .ipa file in this case?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like missconfiguration in xcode.

I recommend reading and doing step by step like described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH13-SW1

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW1

Without real project file it will hard to tell exactly whats wrong.